# ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) PDF Knit Error

Tags: r, pdf, latex

I'm trying to knit a report as a PDF in RStudio. The code I have so far works fine (I've been testing it chunk by chunk) until it gets to the below chunk:

````
## HCT-CI

```{r}
summaryTable(y=wdata$HCTCI.score, table.title="HCT-CI Raw Score",     y.labels="Number of Readmissions")

summaryTable(y=wdata$HCTCI.score, table.title="Readmissions",     freq.tab=T, y.name="HCT-CI Raw Score")

summaryTable(y=wdata$HCTCI.3cat, table.title="HCT-CI Score (3     Groups)", caption_heading="Note:", caption="1: Score=0; 2: Score=1-2;     3: Score=3+", freq.tab=T, y.labels=c("0", "1-2", "3+"))
```

\pagebreak
````

My goal is to generate the output successfully as a PDF.

It's the same functions and format I've used in all the other chunks. When I run the chunk by itself, it also works. I've looked up the issue on google and other stackoverflow posts, but am having a hard time applying their solutions as they all use HTML or a different language.

My full report looks something like this (with some chunks taken out for the sake of brevity):

DOCUMENT BEGINS

````
---
title: 
- \vspace{2in}Analysis for Study$\colon$ Readmissions
subtitle: 
- \vspace{.2in}\emph{`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`}
author:
- \emph{PI$\colon$ Name}
- \emph{College}
- \vspace{.5in}\emph{Author}
- \emph{Position}
- \emph{email}
date:
- \vspace{4in}
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{titling}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{pic.png}}
- \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pic.png}}
- \fancyfoot[C]{Department}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
geometry: left=.5in,right=.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in
mainfont: Times New Roman
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
    highlight: tango
    toc: true 
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    df_print: kable
fontsize: 12pt
---

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

```{r setup, include=FALSE} 
source("Revised Code.R")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='Figs/', fig.align='center',  fig.pos="H", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,  results = 'asis', fig.width = 6.5, fig.height = 4.5, dev = 'pdf')
````

\pagebreak

## Summary of ___ within 100 days

```
summaryTable(wdata, table.title="Within 100 Days", y.labels="Number of Readmissions")

summaryTable(wdata, table.title="Within 100 Days", y.labels="Number of Readmissions", freq.tab=T)

summaryTable(wdata, table.title="Within 100 Days", freq.tab=T, y.name="Readmission", y.labels=c("No Readmission", "Any Readmission"))
```

\pagebreak

## Association Between Readmissions and Donor Type

```
summaryTable(y=wdata$donor, table.title="Donor Type", freq.tab=T, y.name="Donor Type")

summaryTable(y=wdata$donor.3cat, table.title="Association Between Readmissions and Donor Type (3 Groups)", freq.tab=T, y.name="Donor Type", y.labels=c("Matched Sibs", "MUD", "Others"))

regTable.logistic(formula=wdata$readm.any~as.factor(wdata$donor.3cat), response = "Readmission", y.name="Donor Type (3 Groups)", y.labels=c("MUD vs Matched Sibs", "Others vs Matched Sibs"))

summaryTable(y=wdata$readm.any, bygroup=as.numeric(wdata$donor.3cat), freq.tab=T, bygroup.name="Donor Type", y.name="Readmissions", bygroup.labels=c("Matched Sibs", "MUD", "Others"), caption_heading="Note:", caption = "0: No Readmission; 1: Any Readmission")
```

\pagebreak

## Association

### HCT-CI

```
summaryTable(y=wdata, table.title="Raw Score", y.labels="Number of Readmissions")

summaryTable(y=wdata, table.title="Readmissions", freq.tab=T, y.name="Raw Score")

summaryTable(y=wdata, table.title="Score (3 Groups)", caption_heading="Note:", caption="1: Score=0; 2: Score=1-2; 3: Score=3+", freq.tab=T, y.labels=c("0", "1-2", "3+"))
```

\pagebreak

DOCUMENT ENDS

It's only when I attempt to knit it as a PDF do I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   )
l.1949 \item
             \underline{\textit{Note:}} 

Error: Failed to compile Revised_Code.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Revised_Code.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you share `Revised_Code.tex`?

Comment: From the tex perspective: the problem is that you cannot start a new table row with `[` because `\\[....` has a special meaning in tables. As a workaround, one can "hide" the square braket by writing `{[1,3)}` etc. The following tex code would work: https://pastebin.com/EYUQ0ty2

Comment: Do you know where the cell entries like `[1,3)` come from? Are the generated on-the-fly or are they from some input?

Comment: They could possibly be coming from the input; for that specific cell [1,3] it calculated the frequency percentage based on the data I put in. That could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." error may also appear when a numerical value is entered for the chunk option `out.height`. For example `out.height=200` generates this error, it should be replaced by `out.height="200px"`.